# Can't solve "header have already been sent" error

Tags: php, symfony, laravel, content-management-system

I have installed [Flarum](http://flarum.org/) and tried to create my first extension. I have followed the tutorials and "required" my extension through the root folder's composer.json and ran "composer update". It popped up in my Admin Dashboard of Flarum and as soon as I enabled it I got this error throughout the whole site:

> RuntimeException Failed to start the session because headers have
>   already been >sent by
>   "/srv/users/serverpilot/apps/myapplication/public/workbench/flarum-ext-yogi/bootstrap.php" at line 4.

Extension folder contains only two files: composer.json and bootstrap.php

This is the content of bootstrap.php:

```
<?php return function () { echo 'Hello world!'; };
```

Here's my callstack information: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YU618.png

As soon as I remove the "echo" from the bootstrap.php my site starts working again. I tried cleaning my cookies and cache but it didn't help.

What might be the reason for this? Why would a simple echo break the whole site?

Comment: Probably Flarum sets the headers for each page of your site (search the code base for the method `header()`. Whenever you output data (in this case the echo outputs data), the headers of the HTTP response cannot be changed anymore, eventhough flarum still wants to do that. Read the following link for more information : http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Good News

You've already solved your own question by finding the problem is in `bootstrap.php`.

### Solution

Delete the anonymous function in `bootstrap.php`. It `echo`s content while application is still in the loading process. If you want to `echo` someting on the page, do it in the right place, where the application wants you to do it.

### Wait, but why?

There's one principle at work here. **HTTP content must have HTTP headers prior to the content.** Due to this principle, using `echo` sends content, thus also forces PHP to send headers along with it.

There is TONS of documentation on 'Headers Already Sent' errors. I can merely offer a quick explanation to maybe save you reading time.

Basically, PHP auto-sends HTTP headers when it detects you have generated HTTP content. This is exactly when you `echo` something.

This is all fine and dandy and helpful. But many applications like to make manual changes to the HTTP headers prior to sending them.

There's a place applications do this during file loading / initialization.

You skipped this step and delivered your output too early.

### Enter Joe Shmoe Web Developer

So some poorly written software uses `echo` too early, it screws the whole thing by forcing PHP to send headers with the `echo`ed content but it's before the application wanted.

So when the application gets to where it likes to make header changes, PHP stops the application and says a *future stackoverflow user* tried `echo` before everything was properly initialized (aka. Headers Already Sent).

### Real World Example

It's like writing a letter to your grandmother without thinking it all the way through. You place your usual special edition Brazzers postal stamp on the envelope. Then you're so pleased with the content of your letter that you lick it shut and drop it at the post-office. The next day you return to the office and say to the post-man you made a terrible mistake and want to change your envelope. The post office will tell you it's already been sent. You sent the envelope yesterday with your content.

Answer (score 0):

If you output something like

```
echo 'Hello world!';
```

before

```
`header("something");`
```

You need to put your code after. You probably have a page included that contains header